# Unsure what set this is

Tags: set-identification, sets

I have a LEGO set without box or instructions. Some information about it is that it has a brick that’s kind of odd. It’s clear but at the bottom it isn’t and it has some type of metal in it the bag should all over say 135149. And I’m pretty sure it is not the Star Wars set. As I remember the box faintly.[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is:

[31051-1: Lighthouse Point](https://brickset.com/sets/31051-1/Lighthouse-Point)
[image]

based on the [1 x3 brick in Medium Blue](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3622&colorID=42&in=A) and the Red Plate, Modified 1 x 4 with 2 Studs without Groove

The "odd' brick is  [Dark Bluish Gray Electric, Light Brick 2 x 3 x 1 1/3 with Trans-Clear Top and Yellow LED Light (Glows Orange)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=54930c02&idColor=85#T=C&C=85)

Comment: Spot on! I can hardly see modified 1 x 4 plate in Red. Not sure how have you spotted it as all of them look like tiles. I would have used Round Corner 2 x 2 Macaroni in Red as a second part to confirm the set.

Comment: I saw some instructions and it was right the bag was shiny due to tape on it. (The tape was on because I was moving and the set was opened)